# How can I get a property name inside the property itself in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a way I can get a property`s name inside the property itself?

I mean something like this:

```
let myObj = {
    myProperty: {
        name: <propertyName>.toString()
    }
};

console.log(myObj.myProperty.name); // Prints `myProperty`
```

Comment: the object inside does not know its parent object.

Comment: Is that what you need ? : console.log(myObj['myProperty'].name)

Comment: @carton yes, the result is this one, but I would like to do this without statically referring the properties name. Apparently there is no way of doing this on JS :(

Comment: @LucasAraujo Maybe that exemple can help you, making  a loop in your object: https://codepen.io/cartons/pen/dmvgOX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. There's nothing available when the object initializer is evaluated that provides that information.

Presumably if this were a one-off, you'd just repeat the name. If it's not a one-off, you could give yourself a utility function to do it:

```js
// Define it once...
const addProp = (obj, name, value = {}) => {
    obj[name] = value;
    value.name = name;
    return obj;
};

// Then using it...
let myObj = {};
addProp(myObj, "myProperty");
addProp(myObj, "myOtherProperty", {foo: "bar"});

console.log(myObj.myProperty.name);
console.log(myObj.myOtherProperty.name);
```

Comment: The solution with the utility function will do! Doesn't look awesome, but it will help with my scenario.
Thanks!